# How to say wow in chinese and stretch it out? Woooaaaaah

Tags: translation, usage, onomatopoeia

How do you say "waaa~" in chinese? Woooaaaaaa~

To express being dazed by awe. I know 哇 exists but I'm not sure how to exaggerate it.

Comment: You can use punctuation, e.g. "哇~~~~~~!" ; " "哇!!!!!!!!!!";  "哇........!"

Comment: do it this way will be exaggerated enough: 卧槽

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 哇噢 (噢 and 哦 can be used interchangeably here)
- 哇噢噢噢噢… (add more 噢 for exaggeration)

---

### Update

In the [search result](https://s.weibo.com/weibo/%25E5%2593%2587%25E5%2599%25A2%25E5%2599%25A2%25E5%2599%25A2) of 哇噢噢噢 on Weibo, many example sentences can be found. Here is one example:

哇噢噢噢恐怖片爱好者狂喜！(Woooow, horror lovers being ecstatic!)

Comment: Do you have examples of these being used in online messaging or in novels by natives?

Comment: @theonlygusti You can find examples in my updated answer. 哇噢噢噢 is an informal expression commonly used online, but I didn't see good examples in novels.

Answer (score 1):

Wowwwww is not commonly used in chinese conversation
But you can use 哇塞(wasai)(with the syllable "ai" stretched out) or simply type "ohhhhhhhhhhhh" on the internet.

Comment: 哇塞 has a more exaggerated tone than "Wowwwww". Instead, "哇噢" may be a closer expression in tone.